PowerBI Join Tables Based on Index Column and Name of Tables
I'm using PowerBi (desktop version). I have a table with a list 102 library names and an index column, like so:



Library
Index




Lib1
1


Lib2
2



I have a 102 separate tables containing the opening and closing hours of each library. As you can see below, all the names of tables are formatted in this format Hours (1), where the number in the parentheses correspond to the index number in the library table above. For reference, the data in the hours table is like this:



DOW
Opening
Closing




Mon
9
20


Tues
9
20



The join I'm hoping to create is something along the lines of this, where each library will be repeated 7 times.



Library
DOW
Opening
Closing




Lib1
Mon
9
20


Lib1
Tues
9
20


Lib1
Wed
9
20


Lib1
Thurs
9
20


Lib1
Fri
9
20


Lib1
Sat
9
17


Lib1
Sun
9
12



Any thoughts on how to create this type of join?


I have a 102 separate tables containing the opening and closing hours of each library you need to fix your DB schema.

To answer your specific question, add a Custom Column to your first table with the following:
Expression.Evaluate("#""Hours (" & Number.ToText([Index]) & ")""", #shared)

Then after that, you can expand this new column.

I am curious though, why you have a query of hours per library? What is the source of each of these queries? (Web Query?). I ask since you can probably solve this without having 102 queries, and instead use a Power Query Function in your first table.

Thank you for the solution! It worked just like you had indicated. Your speculation about the source of the query is correct. It data is in this format because of a web query, which is not something I have control of. However, your solution does exactly what I need it to do so thank you again for your help!
